# c# lucene 4.8 slow search: 400ms -> to 30ms?

Tags: c#, performance, search, lucene

i try to speed up my lucene-search in my wpf-application.
i hoped that my search would be in the range of about 30ms.

87 search items where found in the index. So that is not very much.
But Stopwatch timer says, it takes around 400ms, way to much for me.

So can u check my code, how i can improve code ?
I also still measured time from the beginning of the try block to the foreach, so there is no big waste of time through init; but it is not (0 ms).

```
    List<CardView> aAll_CardView = new List<CardView>();

        try
        {
            SortField field        = new SortField(LUCENT_STATE_MAIN, SortFieldType.STRING);
            Sort sort              = new Sort(field);

            searchManager.MaybeRefreshBlocking(); // execute with fresh index searcher

            var searcher   = searchManager.Acquire();
            var topDocs    = searcher.Search(aBooleanQuery, 100, sort);
            var _totalHits = topDocs.TotalHits;

            CardView aCardView = null;
            // measured time: take ~400-500ms grr !!!!
            foreach ( var result in topDocs.ScoreDocs)
            {
                #region iterate through findings and put lucene data into CardView list

                var aDoc = searcher.Doc(result.Doc);

                aAll_CardView.Add(new CardView
                {
                    // all fields are defined as TextField()...

                    // must be first,  because used in e.g. Nr_Main
                    RelatedItemCount = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_RELATED_ITEMS),

                    Nr_Main          = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_NR_MAIN),
                    Nr_Parent        = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_NR_PARENT),
                    Antwort          = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_ANTWORT),
                    Beschreibung     = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_BESCHREIBUNG),
                    Note             = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_NOTES),

                    Question_Main    = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_TITLE_MAIN),
                    Question_Parent  = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_TITLE_PARENT),
                    Book             = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_BOOK),
                    Date_Create      = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_DATE_CREATED),
                    Date_LastEdit    = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_DATE_LASTEDIT),
                    Bibelstelle      = aDoc.Get(LUCENT_BIBELSTELLE),
                    // ParseCore just uses TryParse to get enum for state
                    Status_Main      = ParseCore(aDoc.Get(LUCENT_STATE_MAIN)),
                    Status_Parent    = ParseCore(aDoc.Get(LUCENT_STATE_PARENT))
                });

                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            string exp = e.ToString();
            new JMsg(exp).ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
```

Comment: have you ever tried to measure the time which is really needed to get the records out of the index and the time you need to map it's attributes to the CardView? just wondering which one takes more time

Comment: im not sure if i get you. The aDoc.Get(xxx) method takes the value out of the index, the next step is map them to CardView-Class properties. Thats all in the foreach(), which i measure to 400-500ms.

Comment: One way to make indexes faster is to delete most of the data being indexed :)  Another way is to write a faster one yourself.  Ooh and a third way is to get better hardware.  But I am curious - why is 400ms too slow in a UI application?

Comment: because in the future, there will be more hits. I now have 87 hits. And in some time there could be 1000 hits per search. So calculating up, u have waiting time, when switching search data. Look at some book apps. When u do searching there in some good programmed apps, even search to one single "e" in all of the text of the books, it immediatley returns the result, no delay, giving 31062 hits. amazing what is possible..... so im search for MY bottleneck.

Comment: my goal is to get out if lucene is fast enough in any scenario to stay in a response time between 15-30ms, no matter how big the search is. Because than my interface lucene is fast enough, and i have to keep up with .net and maybe real time problems ....

Comment: well i'm not familliar with the .net version of lucene but 500ms looks pretty long for such a simple search. so my idea was to splitt the lucene code which is searching and extracting results from the mapping logic and measure those two things to find out which one takes more time.